# Connecting to domain.com Mysql Database

Tags: python, mysql, database, web-hosting

I am currently having difficulties connecting to MySQL database hosted on domain.com in python. I have the following script:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (
     host = "host.domaincommysql.com",
     user = "usernamefromdb",
     passwd = "password",
     db = "dbfromhost")
 orders_sql = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql("SELECT* FROM orders", con=conn))['Date']
```

I am trying to retrieve the date column in the orders table of the database. I have tried specifying a port (3306) to the connection parameters with no luck. I receive the following error:

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.domaincommysql.com' (10060)"

I have tried searching this before posting only to find that the questions asked are either about local host connections (which I can connect to fine fyi) or unspecific to this problem as they provide no resolve. Out of frustration, I've also contacted domain.com and naturally received no help.

Thanks in advance. Any help on this frustrating issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess the DB is only available internally in their network. You might get further with an SSH port forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that no MySQL server software is running on that machine, or that a firewall at your hosting service rejects connections from the machine running your Python program.

It is common for hosting services to rig their firewalls to ignore MySQL connection attempts from the worldwide internet, and only allow them from within their own network. There may be a configuration setting on your dashboard saying something like "allow external MySQL connections" or "whitelist my IP address for MySQL".

Or you may be able to use ssh tunnelling. Explaining how to do that is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but you can look it up.